# can not start spring mvc 4 application without web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, servlet-3.0

I am trying to deploy `spring mvc 4`  web application without `web.xml` file using `@Configuration` annotation only.
I have

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
            "DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("ge.dm.icmc.config.WebConfig");
    return context;
}
```

}

and my `WebConfig.java` class looks like :

```
@Configuration    
@EnableWebMvc     
@ComponentScan(basePackages="ge.dm.icmc")    
public class WebConfig{

}
```

But when I try to start the application, I see in log :

> 14:49:12.275 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Could not load class for config location [] - trying package scan. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

If I try to add web.xml file, then it is started normally.

Comment: You shouldn't use `setConfigLocation` but `register` instead.

Comment: I would also suggest instead of implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` using one of the convenience classes provided by Spring.

Comment: Could you tell me what do u mean under "convenience classes provided by Spring" ?

Comment: The [`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) for instance. Check the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) and subclasses of the `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the method `setConfigLocation` which, in this case, is wrong. You should use the `register` method instead.

```
private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(ge.dm.icmc.config.WebConfig.class);
    return context;
}
```

However instead of implementing the [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) I strongly suggest using one of the convenience classes of Spring for this. In your case the [`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) would come in handy.

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() { return null;}

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class};
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"*.html"}; 
    }
}
```